# Why my element isn't at the middle of his border?

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why when i add border to this element, the element isn't at the center of the border

[image]

My css :

```
.arrow
{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

My html :

```
<span id="slide_left" class="arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
```

I just want to have the element at the center of this border !

If someone knows why ? :)

Comment: you need to center the element inside the arrow, not the arrow

Comment: Oh yes I got it !

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code:

```
.arrow{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is way too much going on in your css. Just start simple.

```
.arrow{

    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:50%;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but like this the circle isn't  a real one, and my border has to be a circle :)